# Authenticating users in Laravel via Windows Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, iis, laravel-5

I have PHP running in a Windows domain on IIS 7.5.

Windows authentication is turned on via IIS, so the users DOMAIN\USERNAME is available via `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` in PHP.

I've just installed Laravel 5 for a new internal website, and need a way to authenticate users in Laravel using a single sign-on type of way.

The end users should be authenticated in Laravel without having to sign in anywhere, as they are already authenticated to the domain..

I've searched around, and literally can't find anything relevant!

Is there anything written about this? Surely its quite a common use-case? Where should I start in terms of reading, or if anyone can help directly?

Comment: I don't think it's quite a common use case, most servers are based on linux and not windows, because ms technology costs more . So you would prefer MS only if you would do something MS related (Iike a C# project). What you basically want is something unique to identify the user on your DB. Then compare that unique thing with an $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] unique attribute and log in that user like usual. Not sure about this but whats came up to my mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']` is set, you can use something like the following in your `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate`:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate {

    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->server('AUTH_USER') && ($user = User::where('username', $request->server('AUTH_USER'))->first()))
        {
            $this->auth->login($user);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Now add the [middleware to your routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes).

This however does assume your user already exists. You can change the redirect to create a user on the fly if the user does not exist, if you want that.

Comment: Thanks, since the `Authenticate.php` hadn't existed, I had to add not only the file, but also register it in `$middleware` on `kernel.php`, then had to register a custom name in `$routeMiddleware` with a custom name, leaving the old auth intact. I also don't seem to need Guard, the construct, and the prop, whats the use case for this?   Will it work without it, and just not safe?