# laravel connection sql server with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, laravel

How can I connect to SQL Server via Windows Authentication on Laravel?

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST= host
DB_PORT= port
DB_DATABASE= database
DB_USERNAME= ?
DB_PASSWORD= ?
```

Comment: have you changed your default driver to sqlserver?

Answer (score -2):

There is no direct way to do it, You can follow the following way as described in [here](https://laravel.io/forum/06-23-2015-authenticating-users-in-laravel-via-windows-authentication)

1. check if we have authenticated the user in laravel with
   **`\Auth::check()`**
2. If this is set I see if we have the user in Laravel
   **`$user = \User::find($id);`**
3. If the user exists I log them in
   **`\Auth::login($user);`**
4. If not I create a new user and then log them in
   **`$user = new \User; $user->id = $id; $user->password = 'dummy'; $user->save(); \Auth::login($user);`**
5. if the **`$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`** is not set then I redirect to the log-in page.

Also, you can create a middleware to handle windows authentication as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999372/authenticating-users-in-laravel-via-windows-authentication)